# Inaccessible due to its protection level?

Tags: c#, constructor

I'm still quite new to coding in general, and while this simple program is only meant to be a test to learn how constructors work, I'd still like to know why I'm getting this error.

```
using System;

public class methodTest
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    public methodTest(int i, int j, int k)
    {
        a = i;
        b = j;
        c = k;
    }
}

public class methodObj
{
    static void Main()
    {
        methodTest obj = new methodTest(10, 20, 30);
        Console.WriteLine("obj = " + obj.b);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

I'm not entirely sure why I'm getting the error. The problem is with the Console.WriteLine, where it states it cannot access obj.b. The variables seem to be declared within a public class, so why can they not be accessed? I tried searching for a solution to this, but all the questions I found were much too convoluted for me to get an answer I could translate to my own understanding.
All help appreciated!

Comment: Variables are implicitly `private`. In the lack of an access specifier, they are inaccessible to **anything** that is not that exact class.

Comment: @EBrown it is worth noting that the private variables here, a, b, and c, are more precisely called *fields.*

Comment: @phoog Indeed, adding that to my answer as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Even though the variables are in a public class, they must be declared as public as they are private by default.

See: [Access Modifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)

> Class members, including nested classes and structs, can be public,
>   protected internal, protected, internal, or private. **The access level
>   for class members and struct members, including nested classes and
>   structs, is private by default**.

It is best practice to use capitalized names and [properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) for public variables.

```
public A { get; set; }
```

Properties allow you to control the access of reading/writing of the member, as well as adding logic when they are read or set.

Answer (score 5):

Access modifiers are keywords used to specify the declared accessibility of a member or a type. This section introduces the four access modifiers:

The following five accessibility levels can be specified using the access modifiers:

1. **public**: Access is not restricted.
2. **protected**: Access is limited to the containing class or types
   derived from the containing class.
3. **internal**: Access is limited to the current assembly.
4. **protected internal**: Access is limited to the current assembly or
   types derived from the containing class.
5. **private**: Access is limited to the containing type.

Every members in `C#` are implicitly private, so in your question the `a,b` and `c` are defined as `private` and so you could not access to them from outside of `methodTest`.
for more information you may need to look at this page :
[Access Modifiers (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)

Good Luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is **not** caused by the constructor. You get the error because the field `methodTest.b` is private (in C#, fields are private by default; you need to specify an explicit modifier, so something like `public int b;`).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that, in C#, variables (in this case, `fields`) are marked as `private` if they are not specifically marked with an access modifier.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx

Classes and structures default to `internal`, fields, methods, events, properties, etc (basically, **all** members of `classes` and `structures`) default to `private`.

Changing `int a` to `public int a` (and the same for b/c) will fix it.

Though, I recommend **not** doing that. Instead, make a property for each.

```
public A { get { return a; } set { a = value; } }
public B { get { return b; } set { b = value; } }
public C { get { return c; } set { c = value; } }
```

Comment: Also doesn't the private by default rule apply to all class and struct members, including properties, methods, and events?  These are not variables.

Comment: Yes. It does. Private is assumed for all members of classes and structures.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access your integers a, b, and c from outside of the class they are instantiated in, you have to declare them as `public`.  However a cleaner option is to use a property, such as:

```
public int A {get; set;}
public int B {get; set}
public int C {get; set;}
```

This sets up you up to potentially limit write access from outside classes, while still leaving the the properties open for reading, such as:

```
public int A {get; private set;}
public int B {get; private set}
public int C {get; private set;}
```