# C# username is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: asp.net

I need pass on **HyperLink** tag on the property **NavigateUrl** the value of variable **username**.

When c# gives this compile error?

> C# username is inaccessible due to its protection level

My code below.

```
    string[] strMat;
    string username;


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            username = Page.User.Identity.Name.ToLower();
            strMat = username.Split('\\');

            if (strMat.Length > 0)
            {
                username = strMat[strMat.Length - 1];
            }
        }
    }




<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" 
               runat="server" 
               NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("Default.aspx?id={0}", username.ToString().ToUpper()) %>' >
</asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inaccessible due to its protection level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302825/inaccessible-due-to-its-protection-level) or  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125077/is-inaccessible-due-to-its-protection-level

Comment: `public string username;` ?

Comment: @TheGeneral Thanks a lot !!!!

Answer (score 1):

If not specified the default is "private". Change it to "public". Better yet, make it a property:

```
public string UserName { get; set; }
```