# Data binding to Switch

Tags: data-binding, parameters, binding, switch-statement, .net-maui

I am trying to change bool based on what is on turned on on Switch. Method works in xaml.cs but I would like to do this in ViewModel. Is it posibble? And if yes what should I do?

git:https://github.com/wojblaz/Clicer-Game---final/commits/master/Clicer%20Game

**In ViewModel i get an error:**
"ClassicMode.ModeSelector" is inaccessible due to its protection level.

(Mode selector is name of switch)
The same happens without ClassicMode(it is a name of view).

View(Xaml) - ClassicMode:

Is x:Type defined good?
`

```
        <Switch
            x:Name="ModeSelector"
            IsToggled="False"
            Toggled="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodels:ClassicModelViewModel}}, Path=BindingContext.ModeSelector_ToggledCommand}"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="0"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
```

`

Xaml.cs - BindingContext
`

```
using Clicer_Game.ViewModels;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;


namespace Clicer_Game.Views;

public partial class ClassicMode : ContentPage
{
    public ClassicMode()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new ClassicModelViewModel();
    }

}
```

`

ViewModel

`

```
    private bool IsTime;
```

```
        [RelayCommand]
        private void ModeSelector_Toggled()
        {
            if (ClassicMode.ModeSelector.IsToggled)
            {
                IsTime = false;
            }
            else
            {
                IsTime = true;
            }
        }
```

`

What parameter should I use in ModeSelector_Toggled method?

Comment: It is not possible to directly access a UI element of View, from ViewModel. Use MVVM and DataBinding. (You are trying to write maui code, without learning the fundamentals. I recommend spending several days following docs, tutorials, and youtube videos. Download working code, and modify it, before trying to write your own code. I know it is a bit challenging currently; Maui materials are still in short supply. Sometimes, Xamarin Forms material will help, for advanced topics. But first learn the basics of Maui.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302825/inaccessible-due-to-its-protection-level). It tells about `Inaccessible due to its protection level` in details. Select `ModeSelector` and press F12, you should see this:

```
private global::Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Switch ModeSelector;
```

The access level is `private`.

**Method 1**: You can create a Switch in code, and check this [official code](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/blob/main/6.0/UserInterface/Views/SwitchDemos/SwitchDemos/Views/SwitchCodePage.cs). Remember to make Switch's access level `public`.

**Method 2**: Write relevant code directly in `MainPage.xaml.cs` file:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Switch_Toggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
    {
      if (ModeSelector.IsToggled)
            {
                IsTime = false;
            }
            else
            {
                IsTime = true;
            }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
pubulic static bool IsTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Command` attribute in `Switch` node. But you cant use Command in Control Events directly. What you can do is use the `EventToCommandBehavior` behavior given by the [CommunityToolkit.Maui](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommunityToolkit.Maui) NuGet package.

Refer this official .NET MAUI documentation for this: [MAUI official docs of EventToCommandBehaviour behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/behaviors/event-to-command-)

For your code you can try the following:

**View:**

```xaml
<Switch x:Name="ModeSelector"
    IsToggled="False"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.Column="0"
    HorizontalOptions="Center">
    <Switch.Behaviors>
        <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
            EventName="Toggled"
            Command="{Binding ModeSelector_ToggledCommand}" />
    </Switch.Behaviors>
</Switch>
```

**ViewModel:**

```cs
private bool IsTime;

[RelayCommand]
private void ModeSelector_Toggled()
{
    if (ClassicMode.ModeSelector.IsToggled)
    {
        IsTime = false;
    }
    else
    {
        IsTime = true;
    }
}
```